# How to drop a subset of MultiIndex "columns" from a Pandas series or dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Iterating over a pandas `DataFrame` using `iterrows()` produces a series of index `Series` pairs (tuples).

```
for timestamp, row in df.iterrows():
```

I am aware that `iterrows()` is slow. Ignoring that issue for now -

Some of the returned rows will contain `None` or `NaN` values. I want to remove these. (**Not** from the `DataFrame` but from a copy of each row returned by `iterrows()`.)

I also want to remove a subset of "columns". Columns are named with a 2-level MultiIndex.

Here's an idea of what the DataFrame looks like:

```
                    AACT                  ABILF                ...
                    open high  low close  open high  low close ...
timestamp                                                                                                                   ...
2022-01-04 00:00:00  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN ...
2022-01-04 00:01:00  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN ...
2022-01-04 00:02:00  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN ...
2022-01-04 00:03:00  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN ...
2022-01-04 00:04:00  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN ...
```

All the values **happen** to be NaN here, however in general that will not be the case.

Because I do not know how to approach this problem, here is some pseudocode:

```
for timestamp, row in df.iterrows():

    row.drop([('AACT', 'open'), ('AACT', 'high'), ('AACT', 'low')])
    row.drop([('ABILF', 'open'), ('ABILF', 'high'), ('ABILF', 'low')])
    row.dropna()

    # remaining data is `('AACT', 'close')` and `('ABILF', 'close')`
    # iff values in this `Series` are non-NaN
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible input for `df` (e.g. output of `df.head().to_dict('tight')`)

Answer (score 0):

There is the `level=...` argument in the `pandas.DataFrame.drop()` method, see the [documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html).

See the following reproductible example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arrays = [
    ["bar", "bar", "foo", "foo"],
    ["one", "two", "three", "four"],
]

tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=["first", "second"])


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 4), index=["A", "B", "C"], columns=index)
df

>>> 
first   bar foo
second  one two three   four
A   0.951324    1.439571    0.381357    -0.442386
B   1.664391    0.615796    -0.879859   -0.916176
C   -0.944747   -0.158825   0.615032    0.545176

df.drop('two', axis=1, level=1)

>>>
first   bar foo
second  one three   four
A   0.951324    0.381357    -0.442386
B   1.664391    -0.879859   -0.916176
C   -0.944747   0.615032    0.545176
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is provided below. The `drop()` function which exists for both `DataFrame` and `Series` objects takes an argument `level` which specifies which level of a `MultiIndex` should be inspected.

`Series` also has the `dropna()` function which drops None/NaN.

```
for timestamp, row in df.iterrows():

    series = row.dropna()
    series = series.drop(labels=['open', 'high', 'low'], level=1)
```